# Do you know the name of this graphics program?

Tags: windows-3.1

My dad always used a graphic program (with clipart-like stuff) on windows 3.x. However, his computer broke down.

The graphic progam had the abbreviations IA, but i cant find the full name/download for it. Anyone know how its fully called or where i can download it?

Comment: What did the program do? Anything how it looked like?

Comment: IconArt is all I can come up with that is graphics related and can be abbreviated as IA.

Comment: Sure it's IA? Might be IC for Image Commander : "Manage images from multiple sources with ease. Image Commander supports more than 30 vector and bitmap formats, and can adjust, resize, or even print images on demand."